# Syntax for Swift 2 for directions step loop

Tags: swift, loops, swift2

Can anyone help with the syntax for this loop in Swift 2. The code is from a very useful tutorial ( http://www.devfright.com/category/map-kit-framework/mkdirectionsrequest/) which covers the route directions but it's in Objective C and I know that a number of elements are now deprecated, such as ++. I'm having problems converting the first two lines of code to Swift 2. Any help much appreciated.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < routeDetails.steps.count; i++) {
            MKRouteStep *step = [routeDetails.steps objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *newStep = step.instructions;
            self.allSteps = [self.allSteps stringByAppendingString:newStep];
            self.allSteps = [self.allSteps stringByAppendingString:@"\n\n"];
            self.steps.text = self.allSteps;


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the index explicitly, forget index loops.

```
for step in routeDetails.steps {
    let newStep = step.instructions
    allSteps += "\(newStep)\n\n"
    steps.text = allSteps
}
```

or still *swiftier*

```
allSteps += routeDetails.steps.map({$0.instructions}).joinWithSeparator("\n\n")
steps.text = allSteps
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. However I am getting an error on like 3 (your first example) of - Consecutive statements on the line must be separated by ';'

Comment: Typo (extraneous closing parenthesis). I edited the answer.

Comment: I used (with slight adaptation) your 'Swiftier' solution. Many thanks for your help which is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 2:**

```
for i in 0..< routeDetails.steps.count {

    var step: MKRouteStep = routeDetails.steps[i]
    var newStep: String = step.instructions
    self.allSteps = self.allSteps.stringByAppendingString(newStep)
    self.allSteps = self.allSteps.stringByAppendingString("\n\n")
    self.steps.text = self.allSteps
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else using the route.step instructions this is how I placed it in a text field on a map. Many thanks to Vardian for solving the problem.

```
    self.allSteps += route.steps.map({$0.instructions}).joinWithSeparator("\n\n")
    self.directionsText.text = self.allSteps
```